# How do I shape my binary classifier model to fit my input data?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

Here is my code.

```py
from pandas import read_csv
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Conv2D


train_df = read_csv("output/train.csv")
valid_df = read_csv("output/validate.csv")

train_images = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_images.flow_from_dataframe(train_df, x_col="file_path", y_col="on_off_str", 
                                                   class_mode='binary', batch_size=8)

validate_images = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validate_generator = validate_images.flow_from_dataframe(valid_df, x_col="file_path", y_col="on_off_str",
                                                          class_mode='binary', batch_size=8)


model = Sequential([Flatten(input_shape=(32,32,3)),
                   Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                   Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)])

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=8, epochs=15, verbose=1, 
                    validation_data=validate_generator, validation_steps=8)
```

I'm trying to create a simple binary classifier using a dataset of 32x32x3 images.

I get the error:

```
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [8,196608], In[1]: [24576,128]
         [[{{node sequential/dense/Relu}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_861]
```

and the interpeter hangs.

If I change the batch size to one in order to make the sizes match
I get a similar error but the interperter no longer hangs.

```
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,196608], In[1]: [3072,128]
         [[{{node sequential/dense/Relu}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_861]
2024-02-05 19:54:54.132353: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:108] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

How do I change the shape of the input or my model? My images are 32x32x3.

Comment: Might not be related to your problem as you flatten them: I recommend that you use the channels as first dimension, here on first glance it should not make a difference. In case of CNNs you would have some XxY image size with C channels so a [C,X,Y] shaped tensor. In case of color images you start with C=3. Overall pass a [Batchsize, C, X, Y] tensor through the network